# Screen space reflection makes my object darker

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor, reflection

I'm applying a texture which was set up by @ChristopherBennett. The texture works well (Using EEVEE Render) until I turn on space screen reflections, which makes it darker, and the objects loses it's anisotropic rays. I have provided the Blend file for further insight.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert for *EEVEE* and usually do not use it so I do not know why this happens - but the problem is the *Refraction* setting. When you enable *Screen Space Reflections* in the *Scene Properties*, you also have to enable *Refraction* there **and** *Screen Space Refraction* in the *Settings* of the material. Which I actually do not understand because I do not see any refractive part in the material, but maybe I did not examine the shader nodetree deeply enough. It seems that the *Tangent* node set to *Radial* has no real (or at least a different) effect when reflections are enabled but refraction is disabled.

[image: screen space refraction]

Comment: Thank you for your information Gordon.